# Unity C#: I attached a material to a model I imported from blender. The material is supposed to change color But it doesn't

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working in Unity c#  and I imported a model. I attached a material to this model which changes color at certain times. Nonetheless, the model does not change color what so ever, even though if I look at the material in the inspector it changes color.

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: i basically wrote material.color = Color.red;

Comment: It was working on a different mesh object before i attached it to my model

Comment: it might have something to do with the fact that i added a texture to it

Comment: The shader of the material is still set to standard though

Comment: Please do not reply to a post 6 days later. By the way, what slot in the Material did you add the Texture to? Also, before I can do anything, I do need to see your full code and a screenshot of GameObject/model you want to change the color. This will help me determine what's wrong with it.

Comment: I Think I figured it out... Nonetheless, thank you very much for your response and sorry for replying late as well as wasting your time with this question.